# to act vs to play

Tags: synonyms

If we speak about a theatre, can we use the verbs **play** and **act** interchangeably?

e.g.

Tom wants to act in 'Hamlet' = Tom wants to play in 'Hamlet'

Are they the same in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not the same.  When you look at the entry for [play](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/play) in the dictionary, you'll see that the only definition that applies to acting is **transitive**, so it requires some direct object: usually a role or a venue.  [Act](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/act), on the other hand, can be used in both transitive and intransitive cases.

Your example, "Tom wants to play in Hamlet," is incorrect, since there is no direct object.  Here are alternatives that are correct (words in square brackets are optional):

> Tom wants to play [the part of] Queen Gertrude in Hamlet.
>
> Tom wants to play the National Theatre in Hamlet.

Both of those sentences have a direct object that is a role (Queen Gertrude) or a venue (the National Theatre).

The verb **to play** can also take a play as the object, but then usually the subject is a theater or a company of actors:

> The Royal Shakespeare Company is playing Hamlet this spring.

Here it is a synonym of the verb **to stage**, which is probably more commonly used in this sense.

Going back to the verb **act**, it can be either intransitive:

> Tom wants to act in Hamlet.

or transitive:

> Tom wants to act the part of Queen Gertrude in Hamlet.

The transitive usage is probably less common, with "play" being more frequently used for talking about acting in a particular role.

Comment: *Tom wants to play the National Theatre in Hamlet* doesn't strike me as a valid English utterance.